# Why might a AC Tear (Grade III) increase susceptibility to Trapezius strains?

Tags: injury-prevention, shoulders, conditioning, neck, trapezius

If someone sustained a grade III Acromoclavicular separation and performing all the relevant physio, maintained good on-going general health and fitness and also good shoulder strength and mobility - why might this person be more susceptible to straining their upper trapezius?

Comment: Currently this is asking for personal medical advice which isn't on topic here. If you can edit it, it could be nominated for reopening, but would need to be carefully worded. Unfortunately, the best answer is to see a PT or similar, since they can get hands on and see what/why and what to do about it,.

Comment: @JohnP - is this more acceptable for SEPF?

Comment: It's still borderline, but it's much improved. I'll open it, but it still may get locked by the community.